# Is there an easy way or script to let me email direct from Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, adobe-illustrator

I do a lot of artwork and I really wish there was a way i could email direct from Illustrator. I have to manually save as PDF then go and find the file then right click it and do `send to > mail recipient` etc etc.

I know illustrator takes scripts etc, is there a way I could do something that would just let me send the current file to email as an attachment?

Comment: This sounds like a great question, only it lacks effort on your part. We are not a script writing service. This means you need to attempt something first, then let us know where you got stuck. Take a minute to read [ask], then [edit] your question to include what research have you done, any scripts you've already tried and where they failed.